חבלי משיח has already been fulfilled
I heard in a conversation that the חבלי משיח have already been fulfilled via the world wars. Does anyone have a source for this?

Sefer Avkat Rochel by Rabbeinu Makir, book 1, signs 1-3. We are long past the era of Chevlei Moshiach. The current era is referred to in Prophets as the time when the “Spirit of Uncleanliness will pass from the Earth” Zechariah 13:2. It is part of the “Days of Moshiach”.

Not sure about already fulfilled but Sanhedrin 98 says we can prevent them with Torah and acts of kindness (mitzvos)

@YaacovDeane - Who is Rabbi Makir?

He is one of the Rishonim. Rabbeinu Makir ben Sar Chesed. Some say from Spain, others say from Lunel in Provence. In the first printed edition from the 1300s, it listed him as a teacher of Rashi. Others place him as a student of the eldest son of the Rosh. That would be the connection to the city of Lunel, which is also associated with Rabbi Yonatan Ben David HaKohen of Lunel who corresponded with Rambam.
